# SQL with LIKE to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two Models below:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class TransactionRule
{
    public int TransactionRuleId { get; set; }
    public string Pattern;
    public string action;
}
```

There is no formal relationship between the two tables in my DB.  However, the TransactionRules contains the column "pattern" which contains a SQL LIKE pattern such as "Hell World%".  The Transactions.Descriptions column is matched against the TransactionRules.pattern column.  This would allow me to geta list of all Transactions and any rules which matcvh against the description.  Hopefully the query below describes this better.

```
select 
    t.*, 
    tr.pattern,
from dbo.Transactions t
left join dbo.TransactionRules tr ON t.Description LIKE tr.pattern
```

I can get this working in SQL without much problem but I am struggling to produce a LINQ equivalent.  I would post what I have attempted so far, but they all produce syntax errors and therefore would add little value to my post.

While I could resort to using SQL, I would really prefer to try this in Linq as it will help me understand Linq better (this is an exercise in learning Linq).

Comment: Are you aware of `EF.Functions.Like`?

Comment: @GertArnold I tried using the EF LIKE function against the pattern column value in a join but couldn't get the correct syntax, this is where I require help

Comment: Don't use join, just use where.

Comment: Never done something like this, but you could try a cross join, eg `(from t in Transaction
  from tr in TransactionRule
  where EF.Functions.Like(t.Description, tr.Pattern)
  select new { t.TransactionId , t.Description, tr.Pattern })`

Comment: @sgmoore - this almost works, but I need the equivalent of a left join between the two.  Where no match is present it should return like the sql query in my question would

Answer (score 1):

In  case anyone else runs into the same problem, I managed to produce the following LINQ Query which implements a left join using the EF LIKE function as the condition for the join:

```
        var list = (from t in db.Transactions
                     from tr in db.TransactionRules.Where(tr => EF.Functions.Like(t.Description, tr.Pattern)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { t.TransactionId, t.Description, tr.Pattern, tr.TransactionClass });
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of LIKE is Contains().
Try to use this in the where clause.

Comment: Although "Contains" would be a suitable solution for now, as far as I know Contains misses some of the features of SQL LIKE which I would like to retain support for in case they are required in the future

Comment: Well, in this case you can try to use something like "SqlMethods.Like()". Take a look in this link : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads)